# Neo4j compare two Arrays, Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to compare two arrays in `Neo4j` cypher query ? I have real estates already created with for each some `amenities` as string property separated with comma.

My need is to get all nodes labeled `Estate` where `amenities split` contain `array parameter`.

```
MATCH (e:Estate)
WHERE (a IN ["Laundry","Dryer"] WHERE a IN SPLIT(e.amenities,","))
RETURN e
```

How to achieve this ?

Comment: Use any or all operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For your use case, it would be much more efficient to update `amenities` to contain a *list* of strings instead of a single comma-delimited string. That way, your query would not need to use `SPLIT` at all. In the following examples, I will continue to use `SPLIT(e.amenities,",")`, but ideally that should be replaced by `e.amenities`.
2. If you want to test whether `amenities` contains *all* of the values in a list, you can use the [ALL](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/predicate/#functions-all) function:

   ```
   MATCH (e:Estate)
   WHERE ALL(a IN ["Laundry","Dryer"] WHERE a IN SPLIT(e.amenities,","))
   RETURN e
   ```
3. If you want to test whether `amenities` contains *any* of the values in a list, you can use the [ANY](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/predicate/#functions-all) function:

   ```
   MATCH (e:Estate)
   WHERE ANY(a IN ["Laundry","Dryer"] WHERE a IN SPLIT(e.amenities,","))
   RETURN e
   ```